# How to execute asp.net button click event from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have one file upload control in my aspx page and need to upload the file without clicking on a button. As soon as the user selects the file from FileUpload Control, file needs to be uploaded into the server.

I have to call a Codebehind method from the JavaScript, I tried using `$("#btnUpload").click()` and `__doPostBack('btnBulkUpload', 'OnClick');` but result is **nothing.**

Can anybody suggest me the solution?

Comment: can you provide both server and client relevant code

Comment: Thanks @MladenOršolić for your response, I have found answer for my question.

Comment: Marking an answer as **not useful** is like degrading the beginners. They can't ask any questions in future if they are blocked. Plz mind before making an answer not useful.

Comment: Not sure if your comment is for me, but i haven't downvoted. I felt i might know the answer and help you hence i asked for a bit more of context.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I got the solution...
I had set the button's **Visible** property to **False** that's the reason it was not working. Now I changed the `Visible="False"` to `Visible="True"` and it's working fine.

Comment: When you set the property of button is visible: false, the DOM element of button is not created. so you can not access the button. that's why the button click is not fired.

Comment: Oh! OK @ChetanSanghani for your elaboration. I really didn't know about it. Thank you.